# Python - How to remove spaces between Chinese characters while remaining the spaces in between a character and a number?

Tags: python, regex, space

the real issue may be more complicated, but for now, I'm trying do accomplish something a bit easier. I'm trying to remove space in between 2 Chinese/Japanese characters, but at the same time maintaining the space between a number and a character. An example below:

```
text = "今天特别 热，但是我买了 3 个西瓜。"
```

The output I want to get is

```
text = "今天特别热，但是我买了 3 个西瓜。"
```

I tried to use Python script and regular expression:

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'\s(?=[^A-z0-9])','')
```

However, the result is

```
text = '今天特别热，但是我买了 3个西瓜。'
```

So I'm struggling about how I can maintain the space between a character and a number at all time? And I don't want to use a method of adding a space between "3" and "个".

I'll continue to think about it, but let me know if you have ideas...Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure: is it Python 3?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])\s+(?=[^\W\d_])', '', text)` if you need to remove 1+ whitespaces in between letters.

Comment: `re.sub(r"(?<!\d)\s+(?!\d)", '', input, 0, re.UNICODE)` should also work fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow brilliant! so it's a combination of a positive look behind and a positive look ahead. Don't know we can use it this way!

Comment: @anubhava thank you as well. I tried yours but got an error saying `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. I'm not very clear about your code though. If you can explain it a bit to me, that'd be great!

Comment: [See this working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uKtXmS/1)

Comment: Python 3 uses Unicode strings by default, and `re.U` is redundant there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand the spaces you need to remove reside in between letters.

Use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])\s+(?=[^\W\d_])', '', text)
```

**Details**:

- `(?<=[^\W\d_])` - a positive lookbehind requiring a Unicode letter immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (remove `+` if only one is expected)
- `(?=[^\W\d_])` -  a  positive lookahead that requires a Unicode letter immediately to the right of the current location.

You do not need `re.U` flag since it is on by default in Python 3. You need it in Python 2 though.

You may also use capturing groups:

```
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_])\s+([^\W\d_])', r'\1\2', text)
```

where the non-consuming lookarounds are turned into consuming capturing groups (`(...)`). The `\1` and `\2` in the replacement pattern are backreferences to the capturing group values.

See a [Python 3 online demo](https://ideone.com/bhPjR1):

```
import re
text = "今天特别 热，但是我买了 3 个西瓜。"
print(re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])\s+(?=[^\W\d_])', '', text))
// => 今天特别热，但是我买了 3 个西瓜。
```

Comment: Just FYI: in case you want to match any Unicode letters but ASCII `[A-Za-z]`, you may replace `[^\W\d_]` with `(?![A-Za-z])[^\W\d_]`: `re.sub(r'(?<=(?![A-Za-z])[^\W\d_])\s+(?=(?![A-Za-z])[^\W\d_])', '', text)`