# regexp allow chinese or alphabetic characters

Tags: javascript, regex

- I tried to allow input either Chinese  or Alphabetic Character.

  ```
   var name="TEXT" //here input either alphabetic or Chinese Characters 请输入
   let reqChinesePos=/^[\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF]\d{8}$/;
   let reqEnglish=/^[A-Za-z]\d{40}$/

   console.log(reqEnglish.test(name)); //Here true but here also Chinese characters also match.
   console.log(reqChinesePos.test(name)); //Here true but here also alphabetic characters also match.
  ```

**Expected result :**

```
console.log(reqEnglish.test(name));//here only allow alphabetic characters not allow chinese.
console.log(reqChinesePos.test(name));//here only allow Chinese characters not allow English.
```

Comment: See how to correctly match all Chinese chars [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54179646/3832970). Your `[\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF]` only includes few ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Your character class range for Chinese characters seems correct, at least from simple local testing here.  But, I see another problem with both patterns, in that the `\d` should probably be part of the character class, if you want to also allow Roman numerals in both cases.  After making this change, then give a width or range of widths for the input.  Assuming you wanted a width of 8 both, you could try:

```js
var reqChinesePos = /^[\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\d]{8}$/;
var reqEnglish = /^[A-Za-z\d]{8}$/

var name1 = "大猫大猫大猫大猫";
var name2 = "JONATHAN";
var name3 = "BIGCAT大猫";

console.log(name1);
console.log(reqEnglish.test(name1));
console.log(reqChinesePos.test(name1));

console.log(name2);
console.log(reqEnglish.test(name2));
console.log(reqChinesePos.test(name2));

console.log(name3);
console.log(reqEnglish.test(name3));
console.log(reqChinesePos.test(name3));
```

Comment: I can't act based on your comment.  If you found an edge case which I missed, just tell me and I'm happy to edit my answer.