# How can I RegExp for Unicode Blocks in flutter/dart?

Tags: regex, dart

I have some .NET RegExp code I am attempting to translate into Dart/Flutter. I see that Microsoft had some proprietary block names like "IsCJKSymbolsandPunctuation" but similar names exist here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category. Nevertheless, both

```
    var something = "你好".replaceAll(RegExp(r"[\p{InCJK_Symbols_and_Punctuation}]", unicode: true), "");
    log(something);
```

and

```
    var something = "你好".replaceAll(RegExp(r"[\p{Han}]", unicode: true), "");
    log(something);
```

result in [image]

My ultimate target is

```
//        r"\p{IsCJKSymbolsandPunctuation}\p{IsEnclosedCJKLettersandMonths}\p{IsCJKCompatibility}\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionA}\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}\p{IsCJKCompatibilityIdeographs}\p{IsCJKCompatibilityForms}";
```

Is the only way to enter in code points?

Comment: You need `.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\p{Script=Hani}", unicode: true), "")`

Comment: yes that's the answer, put it in the answers and I can approve it

Comment: Do you think Block would work too? I wonder.

Comment: `\p{Block=Hani}` does not work.

Comment: whats the difference between Script Hani and Script Han?

Comment: None, the `Hani` is the code for the Han script, see https://unicodeplus.com/script/Hani

Comment: it's missing chinese punctuation, i may have to go back to the blocks some how

Comment: Ok, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179179/remove-all-spaces-between-chinese-words-with-regex/54179646#54179646) is all you need  I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```dart
var something = "你好".replaceAll(RegExp(r"\p{Script=Hani}", unicode: true), "");
```

`\p{Script=Hani}` will match any Chinese characters, same as `\p{Han}` in PCRE.

A Dart test:

```dart
String text = "Abc 123 - 你好!";
print(text.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\p{Script=Hani}", unicode: true), ""));
```

Output:

```
Abc 123 - !
```